# SDN, cross-store, @GraphProperty return null

Tags: neo4j, spring-data-neo4j

Using the restaurant-social example (and changing the libraries to use the SDN 3.0.0.R1 and Neo4j 2.0.0), I changed it to use postgres as the other datastore.

It writes the entity to each of the datastore correctly, but when ever I tried to read anything back out, I only get the persisted properties of the postgres database come back, anything persisted to neo4j come back as null. Using the neo4j-shell it has saved the foreignId.

Has anyone getting the same issues?

Comment: So it saves correctly to both, neo4j and postgres? It should read-through the properties from both. Can you publish a unit test that shows the behavior?

Comment: It was mainly a few changes of the restaurant-social example, I'll try to get a reduced project with unit tests going and let you know.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if this is the cause, but SDN 3.0.0.R1 is incompatible with Neo4j 2. You should wait for SDN 3.0.0.R2 which supposedly is due to arrive at the end of this month.